# Excluding specific range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a range formula on a Google Sheet that pulls the next future date out from a column containing nothing but dates (column C), starting from the 4th row:

`=MIN(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(C4:C),C4:C>TODAY()))`

This works, but the problem now is that there's a few rows of data within the range that I cannot remove (i.e. they need to stay there) but **not** be counted for the purposes of this cell's calculation. So far, the best I have come up with is this:

`=MIN(FILTER(ARRAYFORMULA(C4:C),C4:C>TODAY(),C4:C<>C58:C64))`
(rows 58 to 64 are the ones I want to exclude)

This formula doesn't throw any errors but I can see it's wrong - the first formula (without the exclusion) shows a value of December 7th for the next upcoming date (which is correct); where the second formula shows December 13th, which while an item on the spreadsheet, is something like the 3rd or 4th date in sequence.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row()` and `isbetween()`, like this:

```
=min(filter(C4:C, C4:C > today(), not(isbetween(row(C4:C), 58, 64))))
```

See [row()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316) and [isbetween()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10538337).

Comment: Amazing, that works. Thank you!